# Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: 2013, pnp

I have been trying to extract data using the new PnP command

```
Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate
```

But I am getting a null reference exception:

```
    Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate -Path PathToFile ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Provisioning.AddDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate
```

It does not give any useful information.
Here is what I tried with always the same result :

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url http://sharepointSite
Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate -Path PathToExistingFile
-List Lists/SimpleEmailTemplates -Query '<View></View>' -Fields 'Title'
```

Or

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url http://sharepointSite
Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate -Path PathToExistingFile
-List SimpleEmailTemplates -Query '<View></View>' -Fields 'Title'
```

Or

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url http://sharepointSite
Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate -Path PathToExistingFile
-List SimpleEmailTemplates -Query ""
```

Not sure what is wrong here. Am I using the command incorrectly ?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that you are using an invalid path thus the template object cannot be instantiated.

You can use `Set-PnPTraceLog -On -Level Debug` to enable debugging mode on any PnP PowerShell Cmdlets. Then you can re-run your command and you should now get the detailed error description that will let you know why the Provisioning Engine is failing.